# Why gdspy library give a tkinter tcl error when trying to use the layout viewer

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the gdspy library which uses tkinter to show a layout preview.
But when trying to use:

```
gdspy.LayoutViewer(library=None, cells=[cell])
```

python give me a:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\InductorGen.py", line 726, in <module>
    gdspy.LayoutViewer(library=None, cells=[cell])
  File "C:\Users\Maël\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gdspy\viewer.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.grid(sticky='nsew')
  File "C:\Users\Maël\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2226, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

here is the code from the layout viewer of gdspy: [gdspy_layoutviewer](https://github.com/heitzmann/gdspy/blob/master/gdspy/viewer.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the gdspy code, it appears that it assumes that the caller is using `grid` inside of the root widget. More correctly, it's assuming there are no other widgets in the root window.

It uses `grid` to inject itself into row zero and column zero of the root window. If your code (or Anaconda itself) is using `pack` in the root widget, that would explain the error that you get.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... But how could i notice this and prevent anaconda from doing it ? Im so sorry but i dont know a lot about that ...

Comment: In fact, i was running my code on jupyter notebook and i works perfectely fine ... but since I run it with anaconda or python (both do the error) it does nt work ...

Comment: OK I found ... I was also using matplotlib wich is also using tkinter ... so i didnt worked ... Now i'm talking to the lib's dev to implement multi-tk compatibilitie